# KivyMD Xcode build error - ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__imaging)

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivymd

I am building a Python KivyMD app with MAC Xcode, the code was able to run, but the app didn't load on the iphonesimulator. The log is below.

MAC - Big Sur
Xcode - 13.1
Python - 3.8

```
2021-11-03 21:36:12.329967+1100 vocgo[9686:99184] Available orientation: KIVY_ORIENTATION=LandscapeLeft LandscapeRight Portrait PortraitUpsideDown
2021-11-03 21:36:12.330145+1100 vocgo[9686:99184] Initializing python
2021-11-03 21:36:12.495467+1100 vocgo[9686:99184] Running main.py: /Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/YourApp/main.pyc
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0.dev0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.2 (default, Nov  1 2021, 20:29:50) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/vocgo"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_imageio, img_tex (img_dds, img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer, img_pil ignored)
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5, 2021-06-06 (installed at "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
2021-11-03 21:36:13.107136+1100 vocgo[9686:99184] Writing analzed variants.
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-19.0.17'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Apple Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Apple Software Renderer'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
Got dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vocgo-fywrtcoideyfwrepueohqjxjodsj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (no such file), '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (no such file), '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vocgo-fywrtcoideyfwrepueohqjxjodsj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (no such file), '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (no such file)
Got fallback dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vocgo-fywrtcoideyfwrepueohqjxjodsj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (no such file), '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (no such file), '/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (no such file)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/vocgo-ios/YourApp/main.py", line 7, in <module>
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/uix/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
     from kivymd.uix.behaviors import SpecificBackgroundColorBehavior
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
     from .backgroundcolor_behavior import (
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/backgroundcolor_behavior.py", line 25, in <module>
     from .elevation import CommonElevationBehavior
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/elevation.py", line 364, in <module>
     from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Pillow-6.1.0-py3.8-macosx-11.6-x86_64.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 95, in <module>
   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Pillow-6.1.0-py3.8-macosx-11.6-x86_64.egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5430FAEF-F9A3-46F7-B9D3-602717473C51/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC1550-5D8A-4DF7-8186-C052833273B0/vocgo.app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Pillow-6.1.0-py3.8-macosx-11.6-x86_64.egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
   File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/dist/root/python3/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
 ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__imaging)
2021-11-03 21:36:14.027017+1100 vocgo[9686:99184] Application quit abnormally!
```

I heard KivyMD still has many issues when built with Xcode. I was not able to find valuable answers about this error. I felt that I have more than one problem. Please shed some light. Thanks heaps.

Comment: I just tried to build and run a non-KivyMD app on my iPad -- an app I had used fine for a year or more -- and got a similar error. So it may not just be KivyMD apps. Also using Big Sur Xcode 13.1 but python 3.7

Comment: Hmm, mine is Python 3.8. Did yours have the same imaging pyinit error?
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__imaging)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome the problem. I don't know exactly which action is a direct fix to the problem. But I am going to list them all below.

One, when build kivy-ios https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios, use the below, don't use pip3 install kivy-ios.

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios.git
cd kivy-ios/
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -e .
```

Two, once the kivy-ios folder is created in your app folder, activate your virtual environment and install cython in the kivy-ios directory, that includes build your kivy, python3, openssl, and other recipe in that.

Three, when creating your Xcode project, run

```
toolchain create <title> <app_directory>
```

under the kivy-ios directory as well.

Four, I used Python3.9 this time.

In the end, your directory should look like this. I also recommend toolchain build all the basic recipes.

[image: Kivy Xcode project screenshot]

Comment: This is a good youtube clip to follow. Thank you to the author PeanutTheAdmin.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gLGyrlgqCU.

Comment: Github Kivy-ios confirmed the reason. The trick is to use - git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios.git
------------
https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/644